# .NET resized images can't be opened in Adobe software

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, photoshop, image-resizing, adobe-illustrator

I'm doing image resizing as follows:

```
private byte[] ResizeImage(System.Drawing.Image image, double scaleFactor)
{
    //a holder for the result
    int newWidth = (int)(image.Width * scaleFactor);
    int newHeight = (int)(image.Height * scaleFactor);

    Bitmap result = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight);

    //use a graphics object to draw the resized image into the bitmap
    using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(result))
    {
        //set the resize quality modes to high quality
        graphics.CompositingQuality = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
        graphics.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        graphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
        //draw the image into the target bitmap
        graphics.DrawImage(image, 0, 0, result.Width, result.Height);
    }

    //return the resulting bitmap
    ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
    return (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(result, typeof(byte[]));
}
```

Whilst it all appears to work perfectly and for the most part is fine, users are saying they are getting error messages when they try to open the resized images in Adobe software.

Illustrator error:

> The file "MyPhoto.jpg" is in an unknown format and cannot be opened.

Photoshop error:

> Could not complete your request because an unknown or invalid JPEG
>   marker type is found.

As I say I can open the image fine in Windows viewer, Picasa, GIMP etc. 
Just seems to be Adobe software with the issue.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Can you try `Bitmap result = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight, Format24bppRgb);`

Comment: @TaW Gave it a go but same error, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Can you post one of those dubious images?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm running into the same issue.

Comment: @Andrew No, sorry. I never did. I moved employment and it no longer was an issue. If you ever find out about it, I'd really love it for you to post an answer though.

Answer (score 4):

This can be resolved simply by including the `ImageFormat` when saving.

```
image.Save("filename.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg)
```